# Writing a string to file using Ad-Hoc Commands in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I'm a beginner with Ansible and trying to write a string to a file with an **Ad-Hoc command** I'm trying to play around with the `replace` module. The file I'm trying to write to is `/etc/motd/`.

```
ansible replace --sudo /etc/motd "This server is managed by Ansible"
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the [`lineinfile` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) usage and a general syntax for [Ad hoc commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_adhoc.html).

What you are looking for is:

```
ansible target_node -b -m lineinfile -a 'dest=/etc/motd line="This server is managed by Ansible"'
```

in extended form:

```
ansible target_node --become --module-name=lineinfile --args='dest=/etc/motd line="This server is managed by Ansible"'
```

Explanation:

- `target_node` is the hostname or group name as defined in the Ansible [inventory file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html)
- `--become` (`-b`) instructs Ansible to use `sudo`
- `-module-name` (`-m`) specifies the module to run (`lineinfile` here)
- `--args` (`-a`) passes arguments to the module (these change depending on a module)

  - `dest` points to the destination file
  - `line` instructs Ansible to ensure a particular line is in the file

---

If you would like to replace the whole contents of the `/etc/motd` you should use [`copy` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html).

```
ansible target_node -b -m copy -a 'dest=/etc/motd content="This server is managed by Ansible"'
```

Notice one of the arguments is changed accordingly.